# Rails render raw html but escape javascript?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

So I have some user generated content areas of my site. I want them to be able to use html for markup purposes, but I don't want them to be able to execute any arbitrary javascript.

From my understanding raw() will just output everything, html, javascript, and all right into the webpage.

Is there a method that will allow raw rendering of html but not allow rendering of javascript?

Comment: You're looking for an HTML sanitizer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [`sanitize`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper/sanitize).